# Wildcard Tomcat url-mapping or filter-mapping

Tags: apache, tomcat, coldfusion, uri, wildcard

I'm using Railo 3.1 , Tomcat 6 , Apache 2.2.

I'd like to create a servlet-mapping that recognizes any path. e.g.

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/default/*.cfm/*</url-patter>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I know that this url-pattern is incorrect per the specification.

Since this I'm using a content manager, it doesn't make sense for me to have to update the web.xml file each time I create a new /default/thing.cfm file.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: @frogstarr78: Is your target URL of the form **/default/*.cfm?action=a** or **/default/*.cfm/action**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like: 
http://jamiekrug.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/5/22/url-rewrite-goodies-for-apache-tomcat-railo-and-mura-cms